# ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp. When putting in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to run a for loop and grab a bunch of files however the dates for those files are in a bit of a weird format. That looks like `("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M")`. When I pass through `("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")` the loop works fine. However for the former I am getting a value error could not convert string to timestamp.

Here is my shortened code

```
beginning_time = datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)
beginning_time_str = beginning_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M") 
end_time = datetime(year,month,day_end,hour_end,minute)
end_time_str = end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M") 

timerange_HRRR = 
pd.date_range(start=beginning_time_str,end=end_time_str,freq='1H')
timerange_HRRR = timerange_HRRR.astype(str)

grib_file_2d_base = f'{wrf_cases_dir} 
{wrfoutdir}/wrf2d_{domain}_'+timerange_HRRR+'.grib2' 

for fpath in grib_file_2d_base:
print(fpath)
```

Here is a shortened version of the traceback I'm recieving

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent 
call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 31>()
     28 

     30 timerange = 
   pd.date_range(start=starttime,end=endtime,freq='5min')
---> 31 timerange_HRRR = 
pd.date_range(start=beginning_time_str,end=end_time_str,freq='1H')
     32 timerange_HRRR = timerange_HRRR.astype(str)
     35 base_dir = '/network/rit/lab/minderlab_rit/NYSM'

ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
```

Comment: could you please add the exact line that throws the error, and the full error trace? also note that you probably don't want to use colons in file names (e.g. on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `pd.date_range()` function can not interpret your datetime string in the given format with the underscore. You must either pass it a datetime object (`beginning_time`, `end_time` in your example) or a string in a standard datetime format (e.g. `Y-m-d H:M:S`), see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html).

If you really must use your custom datetime format, you have to create the Pandas date range first and format its entries into a string before writing them to a file.

For example:

```
beginning_time = datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)
end_time = datetime(year,month,day_end,hour_end,minute)

timerange_HRRR = pd.date_range(start=beginning_time,end=end_time,freq='1H')
timerange_HRRR = timerange_HRRR.astype(str)

grib_file_2d_base = f'{wrf_cases_dir}{wrfoutdir}/wrf2d_{domain}_'+timerange_HRRR+'.grib2'
grib_file_2d_base = [s.replace(" ","_") for s in grib_file_2d_base]

for fpath in grib_file_2d_base:
    print(fpath)
```